# Fetch device password which is used to lock the device

Tags: android

How to fetch device password which is used to lock the device programatically.

Is it possible in `android` to fetch that password?.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get it ?

Comment: I tried on google but did not find solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that, because of the security of Android, you cannot get any of the information used to lock the device. Otherwise, any application could "break" the security firewalls used to lock the smartphone/tablet.

**Update 10/1/2014**

On a rooted phone, this is possible to get the pin and password lock of the Android smartphone.

If you deal with a rooted smartphone and USB debugging is enabled, cracking of the pattern lock is quite simple. You just have to dump the file /data/system/password.key and the salt, which is stored in a SQLite database under the lockscreen.password_salt key. The corresponding database can be found in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases and is called settings.db (see the figure below). After you got both information you just need to start brute forcing the password.

Comment: I mean i first lock the device from security option then i want to get that key while tapping keys.

Comment: @TGMCians You want to make a keylogger?

Comment: http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/2012/02/28/cracking-pin-and-password-locks-on-android/ This is article for which I was talking.